# Text boxes of different colors in the same application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

One of the frustrating things about xamarin is that in order to do simple things, you have to make endless mess.
my request is very simple
some pages of my application contain white text boxes(entry).
other pages of my application contain red text boxes(entry).

at the application level this is defined in this way

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">#fff</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
```

in java it is possible to set a different theme to an edittext in a very simple way.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
/>
```

i haven't found the solution to do the same thing with xamarin

with xamarin I created a custom render to turn my text box red

```
public class EntryGrayRenderer : EditorRenderer
        {
            public EntryGrayRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
            {
            }
    
        

protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                {
                    Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#a84849"), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                }
                else
                {
                    Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#a84849"));
                }
            }
            IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
            IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");
            JNIEnv.SetField(Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, Resource.Drawable.my_cursor);
        }
    }
```

is the custom render solution the only one to achieve my purpose?

in any case it was not accepted by my boss because the cursor marker should be red but it remained white.

[image]

Do you know how I can overwrite it?

Comment: Does this help: [Change Cursor Color](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11608/how-to-change-the-cursor-color-in-xamarin-forms-text-input-layout)?
Btw: you asked a lot of questions here. For the future, please one question per post. That way it is clear, when it is answered. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I don't think so, your native java android code above would change the marker to red. And yeah, you have to create custom renderers for every enhancements you want. And Custom renders are much more better than using styles in Native language... Its confusing for what you actually want to ask, be specific on what you asking for

Comment: What is `colorAccent` set to in your theme?

Comment: thank you thanks to your example I solved my problem.

actually I already set the color of the cursor as shown in the example.

the problem is that to correctly see the colors set in the my_cursor.xml file I had to delete the following lines from the theme:

<item name = "colorControlActivated"> # fff </item>

<item name = "colorControlNormal"> # fff </item>